# slow start of block synchronization in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

What can I improve or debug to find causes of a delayed start of the block synchronization in geth?

I am running the latest geth (1.4.5-stable-a269a713) on Ubuntu 15.10, I noticed this behavior already on 1.4.4. It takes ~10min to get the first batch of blocks.

The latest output before it stalls for quite a while is `> I0524 22:54:51.049035 eth/downloader/downloader.go:299] Block synchronisation started`

Then the block synchronization slowly picks up, am I not getting all blocks from the bootstrap nodes and have to wait for more connections first?

```
I0524 22:54:51.049035 eth/downloader/downloader.go:299] Block synchronisation started
I0524 23:06:25.499404 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 3 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 5 txs in 2.434135699s. #1569355 [53a9c813 / d03631ff]
I0524 23:06:59.999931 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 37 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 182 txs in 31.936571292s. #1569392 [e45b1b93 / 37fc5741]
I0524 23:09:32.401927 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 1642 txs in 2m32.37937655s. #1569648 [44757652 / f611a137]
I0524 23:11:39.648649 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 1518 txs in 2m7.245587819s. #1569904 [842ff283 / 525a3769]
I0524 23:13:19.716431 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 1151 txs in 1m40.066272988s. #1570160 [28f1684e / 50b11832]
```